# Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, core-telephony, inmobi

I have a SwiftUI/SpriteKit project in which I'm receiving the following error:

> Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 88 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process."

The error seems to be related to the integration of the advertisement framework I'm using (InMobi). It only occurs if this framework is present. It occurs on both simulator and real device.

According to the InMobi [documentation](https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/ios-guidelines/):

> InMobi SDK uses iOS WKWebView to render HTML ads.

**What I've tried:**

- I added the `CoreTelephony.framework` to my project.

I've seen other questions on this topic (it seems related to `WKWebView`), but the "answers" usually suggest suppressing the logs so you don't see the error anymore (lol).

**Question:** What's causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Lurifaxel No, not yet. The error is still present.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error because I was using an extension over CTTelephonyNetworkInfo. The error was gone as soon as I moved the code from the extension to the struct.
[This](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107259) answer provided by Quinn the Eskimo in Apple dev forums helped me understand the issue.